# Attachments in emails sent from Python are not being seen

Tags: python, mime, thunderbird

I can see them in Gmail and it sounds like there's no problem in Outlook, but my Mailspring client can't see them nor can Thunderbird. Not sure why. The attachments are in the message content and their headers seem fine.

[image: mail headers]

This is the code that assembles the message:

```
for filename, data in attached_data.items():

    mime_type = magic.from_buffer(data, mime=True)
    major_type, minor_type = mime_type.split('/', 1)

    if major_type == 'application':
        attachment = \
            email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(
                data,
                minor_type)

    elif major_type == 'image':
        attachment = \
            email.mime.image.MIMEImage(
                data,
                minor_type)

    else:
        attachment = \
            email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(
                data)

    attachment.add_header(
        "Content-Disposition",
        "attachment",
        filename=filename)

    msg.attach(attachment)


raw_message = msg.as_string()
```

This happens with every message. There appears to be no option to block images for unknown senders, nor would I expect it to be done without displaying some visible warning about it. What am I missing?

Comment: I like testing email senders with mailtrap.io . It has a free tier and lets you see headers and the exact form of the messages you are sending. It is also "safe" in that it cannot actually route messages to the public internet.

Comment: Can you capture the full content of each message? Gmail calls this "Show Original" and I assume other clients have similar function. Diff this raw content between each working and not-working client. Are there any differences?

Comment: Good suggestion. I did take the obligatory step of viewing the headers in Gmail, where it will warn you about signing and security issues (this message showed all green; we don't have any actually delivery problems).

Comment: I'll have to do that later. I'm dubious that I'll see anything since Gmail is displaying the attachments just fine (so, presumably, clients that are having issues have something client-specific going on).

Answer (score 1):

Try showing the hidden attachments:

"Because this view mode is not needed by most users and could be confusing to some, it is disabled by default. To enable it, use the Config Editor to change the preference mailnews.display.show_all_body_parts_menu to true."

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/configuration-options-attachments

Mostly images aren't shown as attachments: they are displayed. It's easy for programs to get confused about this: mime isn't even as standard as the HTTP/HTML from which it is derived.

Comment: It's not clear what's supposed to happen next. I would expect to either see the attachments, or a new menu item (taking the name of the config item literally), it doesn't appear to be either. If it is a menu item, I could be overlooking it.